# Why Spring Boot 2.0 application does not run schema.sql?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

While I was using Spring Boot 1.5, on application startup Hibernate executed *schema.sql* file located in */resources* folder when appropriate configuration is set. After Spring Boot 2.0 release this feature does not work any more. I couldn't find anything about this change in documentation.
Here is my *application.properties* file content:

```
spring.datasource.url=...
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Is there some change in Spring Boot 2.0 or is this an bug/issue?

Comment: I have the same problem and no answer below solved it. Any idea?

Comment: none of answers helped me :( after upgrading spring boot to 2.x the db stopped to autoupdate/create new tables

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Check the documents [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc).

> In a JPA-based app, you can choose to let Hibernate create the schema
>   or use schema.sql, but you cannot do both. Make sure to disable
>   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto if you use schema.sql.

You have `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` that's why `schema.sql` is not executed.
Looks like this is the way Spring Boot works.

**Edit**

I think that the problem(not really a problem) is that your application points to a mysql instance.

See the [current Spring Boot properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=embedded # Initialize the datasource with available DDL and DML scripts.
```

The default value is `embedded` - e.g. initialize only if you're running and embedded database, like H2.

Also see the answer of Stephan [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12612). He said:

> Adding spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always to your project is
>   enough.

So try to set:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Even with 
    `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` 
this doesn't work. I just edited original post.

Comment: It works before Spring 2.0, I don't know why it's not anymore but I'm also looking for an answer. I just need to create a schema for `h2` in `schema.sql`, since I have upgraded to 2.0 it stopped working.

Comment: @11thdimension Looks like new major Spring Boot release doesn't support it. It would be nice we can find this in documentation.

Comment: I already tried it, it still didn't work. However it got resolved after I excluded HikariCP dependency added to to Spring Boot 2.

Comment: @EvgeniDimitrov The answer is correct but in my case it goes into some dependency cyclic loop , as show [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/issues/143)

Comment: It worked for me with spring.sql.init.mode=always. why is it different?

Answer (score 33):

## Not embedded (e.g. MySQL)

If you load a database that is **not embedded**, in Spring Boot 2 you need to add:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Check the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#database-initialization):

> ## Database Initialization
>
> Basic DataSource initialization is now only enabled for embedded data
>   sources and will switch off as soon as you’re using a production
>   database. The new `spring.datasource.initialization-mode` (replacing
>   `spring.datasource.initialize`) offers more control.

---

## Embedded (e.g. h2)

I once had a similar problem, even though it was an h2 (so it **was** an embedded DB), my h2 configuration was activated by a `my-test` profile.

My test class was like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest                     // does not work alone
@ActiveProfiles("my-test")
public class MyEntityRepositoryTest {
```

The problem is `@SpringBootTest` alone **did not initialize the test database**. I had to either use `@DataJpaTest` or `@SpringBootTest`+`@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`. Examples

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest                       // works
@ActiveProfiles("sep-test")
public class MyEntityRepositoryTest {
```

or

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest                     // these two
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase          // together work
@ActiveProfiles("sep-test")
public class MyEntityRepositoryTest {
```

Comment: This suggestion has been deprecated and you now in later versions use ´spring.sql.init.mode=always´. See post from @Panagiotis Bougioukos.

Answer (score 19):

### Recent Update

As of Spring Boot **Version 2.7**

the property `spring.datasource.initialization-mode` has been removed.

You should from this version and onwards use the replacement property `spring.sql.init.mode`

Example: `spring.sql.init.mode:always`

[Spring Boot 2.7 changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7.0-Configuration-Changelog)

Comment: Also had to update `spring.datasource.platform=mysql` to `spring.sql.init.platform=mysql`

Answer (score 4):

It works fine for me, you can try it. Set datasource type to what you like instead of HikariCP.

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.type=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Answer (score 3):

There might be another problem causing data.sql not to be executed, If you don't config the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`, the data.sql will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make application run only after excluding Hikary CP like that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Please, see the issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/issues/143)

Answer (score 1):

For me, for some reason, Spring didn't find the schema.sql file in the classpath.
I had to specify it explicitly for it to work:

```
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:/sql/schema.sql
```