# create a schema in postgres while spring boot starts

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I need to create a new schema in Postgres when the spring boot loads. So, it should check if the schema doesn't exist then create a new schema. 
I am using application.properties for database configuration.

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${vcap.services.postgresql-lite.credentials.hostname}:${vcap.services.postgresql-lite.credentials.port}/${vcap.services.postgresql-lite.credentials.dbname}
spring.datasource.username=${vcap.services.postgresql-lite.credentials.username}
spring.datasource.password=${vcap.services.postgresql-lite.credentials.password}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=${DATABASE_SCHEMA}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

The default schema that Postgres uses is public, I need to change that make my own schema, which I'll define in env.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following your application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.schema=${DB_SCHEMA}
```

In your schema file add the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a schema-postgresql.sql file placed in src/main/resources with content: as follows:

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ;

Comment: Do I need to add anything in application.properties?

Comment: You have all the things covered in your application.properties it seems.
You can refer this [link](https://github.com/AbhijeetSakhalkar/SprintBoot/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties) as I have tested it and is working.

Make sure your postgres version is later to 9.1

Comment: I get an error saying: Relation schema_name doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you paste your stacktrace ??

Comment: I guess your postgres version is older

Comment: It’s 9.3. And I’ll attach the stacktrace in question in few minutes

Comment: It’s the same. I also added the sql file.

Comment: I figured out why I got the error. While the application boots, I had command line runner added in profile which adds some dummy data to database. I switched that off, the application runs fine, however there is no schema created. The only schema created is public.

Comment: You need some clean up in the application.properties file. Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438517/why-spring-boot-2-0-application-does-not-run-schema-sql). I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: @nirvair  Were you able to find solution ?  facing same issue need to create schema automatically but not working for me.