# What are the possible values of spring.datasource.initialization-mode?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am configuring a database in Spring JPA and I want to know what the possible values are of `spring.datasource.initialization-mode`. I found [this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) with common properties but it doesn't give all possible values. I'd expect there to be some documentation on all possible values of all properties you can set.

I am using the property in the props section in my `applicationContext.xml` as properties for the `entityManagerFactory`

```
<util:properties id="props">
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.ddl-auto">create</prop>
    <prop key="spring.jpa.show-sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="spring.jpa.generate.ddl">true</prop>
    <prop key="spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto">create</prop>
    <prop key="spring.datasource.initialization-mode">always</prop>
    <prop key="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation">true</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Answer (score 23):

When all else fails, you remember "use the source, Luke!". The values are given in the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/DataSourceInitializationMode.html) of the enum `DataSourceInitializationMode`. Values are `always`, `embedded` and `never`.

Comment: *it doesn't give all possible vallues.*, then how did you concluded your answer ? do you have any official source ? or your own research ?

Comment: Javadoc of an enum should give all possible values. Because that's how an enum works.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in spring boot. In my application.properties field I set spring.datasource.initialization-mode=embedded, but I got a warning that said "Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.datasource.initialization-mode'" Does anyone know a way to specify this in spring-boot?

Answer (score 13):

Forgive me for butting in almost a year late. After having faced a similar problem as explained by `Christine`, I decided to take the clue and begin searching in the `source`. It would appear that the following is detailed in the link here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/DataSourceInitializationMode.html :

> Enum Constant Summary Enum Constants
>
> Enum Constant and Description
>
> **ALWAYS** Always initialize the datasource.
>
> **EMBEDDED** Only initialize an embedded datasource.
>
> **NEVER** Do not initialize the datasource.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, there're 3 options: `always`, `embedded` and `never`.

Note that: the property `spring.datasource.initialization-mode` is outdated.
You may want to consider `spring.sql.init.mode` instead for new projects.

## source for the old one

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012-2019 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.springframework.boot.jdbc;

/**
 * Supported {@link javax.sql.DataSource} initialization modes.
 *
 * @author Vedran Pavic
 * @author Stephane Nicoll
 * @since 2.0.0
 * @see AbstractDataSourceInitializer
 */
public enum DataSourceInitializationMode {

    /**
     * Always initialize the datasource.
     */
    ALWAYS,

    /**
     * Only initialize an embedded datasource.
     */
    EMBEDDED,

    /**
     * Do not initialize the datasource.
     */
    NEVER

}
```

## source for the new

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012-2021 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.springframework.boot.sql.init;

/**
 * Supported database initialization modes.
 *
 * @author Andy Wilkinson
 * @since 2.5.1
 * @see AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer
 */
public enum DatabaseInitializationMode {

    /**
     * Always initialize the database.
     */
    ALWAYS,

    /**
     * Only initialize an embedded database.
     */
    EMBEDDED,

    /**
     * Never initialize the database.
     */
    NEVER

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Behaviour varies w.r.t to the Spring Version
From 2.7 Version of Spring

1. Spring Creates Table using schema.sql and data.sql in classpath for Embedded i.e  memory database
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:**mem**:somedbofyours

I have tried the following configuration

1. Create file based H2

   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/db/eesandb
   spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

Whatever be the above combinations, it didnt create or execute schema.sql in 2.7.4

2. The Following Property spring.sql.init.mode determines creation of DDL,DML by referring schema.sql and data.sql in classpath

Example spring.sql.init.mode = always (or)
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always.

Visit Similar Post [Why Spring Boot 2.0 application does not run schema.sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438517/why-spring-boot-2-0-application-does-not-run-schema-sql)