# Difference between spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl and spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

What is the difference between **`spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl`** and **`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl`**?

I have found in this question: [What are the possible values of spring.datasource.initialization-mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922279/what-are-the-possible-values-of-spring-datasource-initialization-mode) that OP is using both in properties, however it seems like the origin of `hbm2ddl` is hibernate directly not Spring Data Jpa.

Nevertheless, reading the  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42147995/6834044) from another OP, it looks like pass-through only.

However in our commercial project with mariadb, when we do not close our spring boot application gracefully with **`spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create`**, when the application is run again, it deletes old data and creates everything from scratch. On the other hand with **`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=create`** every second run (after no graceful application shutdown) causes key constraint exceptions (DB is not being dropper before creation)

Answer (score 0):

1. From this [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-creating-and-dropping-jpa-databases)

- By default, JPA databases are automatically created only if you use an embedded database (H2, HSQL, or Derby).

You can explicitly configure JPA settings by using `spring.jpa.*` properties. For example, to create and drop tables you can add the following line to your application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Hibernate’s own internal property name for this (if you happen to remember it better) is `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`.

2. From this [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto)

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` This is actually a shortcut for the `"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"` property.

Defaults to `"create-drop"` when using an embedded database and no schema manager was detected. Otherwise, defaults to `"none"`.

3. From this [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc)

- Spring Boot can automatically create the schema (DDL scripts) of your DataSource and initialize it (DML scripts).
- It loads SQL from the standard root classpath locations: `schema.sql` and `data.sql`, respectively.
- In addition, Spring Boot processes the `schema-${platform}.sql` and `data-${platform}.sql` files (if present), where platform is the value of `spring.datasource.platform`.
- This allows you to switch to database-specific scripts if necessary. For example, you might choose to set it to the vendor name of the database (hsqldb, h2, oracle, mysql, postgresql, and so on).